# Overriding not executed for vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml

Tags: magento2.4

I need to override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` . to include some custom fields to address form in new customer registration page.

Active theme is luma. Magento version is 2.4

I have tried customized `edit.phtml` in `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Customer/templates/address/` - didn't work

Then tried in `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Customer/templates/address` - didnt work .

In `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer/template` , the address folder is not existing and there.

Any idea on why the attempted overriding is not getting executed?

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to override this template, you must set up a custom child theme.

1. [Create your custom child theme.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
2. Create the following file in your theme:

   < Vendor >/< theme >/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml
3. Copy/paste the code from:

   vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml

   to your theme's new edit.phtml
4. Make any needed modifications to your theme's edit.phtml file.
5. [Apply your theme](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I ll try that out.